# Is there a ruby gem to get the search ranking of a URL for a given keyword with Google, Bing or Yahoo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-ranking

I am trying to find a gem that will help me get the search ranking of a URL with the popular search engines. I've done a little digging and found some outdated ruby gems - namely:

Keyword Ranking: https://github.com/crowdint/keyword_ranking

Rankstar: https://github.com/crowdint/rankstar/blob/master/lib/rankstar.rb

Both seem to be over 2-3 years old and don't seem to be working (i.e. when I install the gem, create a ruby script and run it, I get nothing returned) - is there a more recent gem that I should be using for this? Thoughts on how to get this data through ruby / rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping Google SERP is not allowed by Google long time ago. They use every methods to stop this kind of actions. There were lots of tools before in different programming languages but none of them could last long. Some tools installed on personal computer could be used but not very stable.

Also, as I knew one years ago, there is no API available for such querying.

I suggest you give up this idea to collect rank data. It's not wise to fight against Google.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Question though - how do companies like SEOMOZ and MicrositeMasters (http://www.micrositemasters.com/) get the SERP data? Are they using some sort of blackhat technique to get the data?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know exactly what they do. But I guess the basic would be: multiple bot servers, tons of proxies, algorithm to mimic human action(browse SERP), strong dev team to react quickly on scraping failure. The cost is high, and the effect is not something open source gems can beat.